# Want to recognize imprint of pill using CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, classification

This might be a rather peculiar question. I have utilized a CNN model to label the colors and shapes of pills and have constructed a classification model using CNN. However, I would like to extract information about the imprints using CNN, just like the paper I'm referencing. I am at a loss as to how to label this information. I'm wondering if there are any examples or references available on how to approach this. I tried looking for the uploaded code on the GitHub repository mentioned in the paper, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I am currently using TensorFlow.

Comment: https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/13/8/5050

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do a quick search for image classification with the openCV library and tensorflow. Here is a pretty good article that may help get you started:
https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/06/22/turning-any-cnn-image-classifier-into-an-object-detector-with-keras-tensorflow-and-opencv/